# How do I restart the barcode scanner (Barcode Scanner.Mobile.Maui)?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-maui.shell

I have the DotNet Maui app.  It contains a barcode scanner (BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui).  When I go to the (Achats) page (Shell) and return to the (Vente) page (Shell) that contains the scanner code bar, I find that it does not work or is inactive, as shown in the image below.
How can I solve the problem?

My code xaml:

```xml
<gv:CameraView 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    OnDetected="CameraView_OnDetected" 
    TorchOn="False"
    VibrationOnDetected="False"
    ScanInterval="50"
    x:Name="cameraScanner"
/>
```

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

I searched the internet and did not find a suitable solution. I tried `cameraScanner.Scanning = true;`

Comment: I'd suggest disabling when you navigate away, then re-enabling it when you navigate back to the page

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this

```
private void MudarCamera_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Camera.CameraFacing = Camera.CameraFacing == CameraFacing.Back ? CameraFacing.Front : CameraFacing.Back;
}
```

create a button that does this action, that's what worked for me

Comment: private void MudarCamera_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        Camera.CameraFacing = Camera.CameraFacing == CameraFacing.Back ? CameraFacing.Front : CameraFacing.Back;
    }